# Error while saving the Spark RDD to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0, datastax

We are trying to save our RDD which will have close to 4 billion rows to Cassandra. While some of the data gets persisted but for some partitions we see these error logs in the spark logs.

We have already set these two properties for cassandra connector. Is there some other optimization that we would need to do? Also what are the recommended settings for reader? We have left them as default.

spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows=1

spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes=1

We are running spark-1.1.0 and spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10 v 2.1.0

```
15/01/08 05:32:44 ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement@3f480b4e
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.87.33.133:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timed out waiting for server response))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:108)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$1.run(RequestHandler.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Ankur

Comment: Is this happening after a while? What is your Cassandra cluster status? CPU usage?

Comment: Yes it happens after some time and only for few stages. Some data gets written to the tables but not all.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar in my four node cluster. It seemed that if I specified EVERY cassandra node name in the spark settings, then it works, however if I only specified the seeds (of the four, two were seeds) than I got the exact same issue. I haven't followed up on it, as specifying all four is getting the job done (but I intend to at some point). I'm using hostnames for seed values and not ips. And using hostnames in spark cassandra settings. I did hear it could be due to some akka dns issues. Maybe try using ip addresses through and through, or specifying all hosts. The latter's been working flawlessly for me.

Comment: We are just passing one of the IP to spark.cassandra.connection.host. Can we pass multiple IPs to this property? But in our case some stages are able to write but only a few fail.

Comment: Yes, as a command separated string: 
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "server1,server2,server3,server4")

Comment: Cool. Thanks!! We had tried with earlier version but it was not . Will try with the current datastax connector.

Answer (score 0):

I realized, I was running the application with spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes=2. I changed it to 1 and there were no exceptions. The exceptions were because Spark was producing data at much higher frequency than our Cassandra cluster could write so changing the setting to 1 worked for us.

Thanks!!